# Update by JPA native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using spring boot repository with native query. While I am trying to update few fields by query and supply wrong values it is not throwing any exception.
here is my code,

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "update tbl_user set is_phone_Verified=true, mobile_verification_otp='XXX', updated_At=:updatedAt where " +
        "phone_number=:registeredMobile and " +
        "mobile_verification_otp=:phoneVerificationOtp", nativeQuery = true)
void updateMobileVerified(@Param("registeredMobile") String registeredMobile,
                         @Param("phoneVerificationOtp") String phoneVerificationOtp,
                         @Param("updatedAt") Date updatedAt);
```

Now, the issue is if I supply even wrong otp value, it is not throwing any exception. From service I am calling this method. and if there is no exception then I am returning true. Please find the service method.

```
@Override
public Boolean mobileVerification(String registeredMobile, String phoneVerificationOtp) {
    try{
        Date date = new Date();
        userRepository.updateMobileVerified(registeredMobile,phoneVerificationOtp, date);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest me some way how can I determine if the update is successful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to determine whether any rows were updated, the `updateMobileVerified` method can be defined to return `int` instead of `void` to indicate the number of rows updated

Comment: Perfect. I can track the number of effected rows by using int. Thanks for the info 

Comment: Glad that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are updating an unknown entity in the database. I highly recommend looking for a `tbl_user` entity by a unique id, like user_id or something like that. If the user doesn't exist, you either throw an exception or return false. In the case the given tbl_user was found, you basically update your desired attributes. This way, you force a strong control over updating users' data. I hope this might clarify your vision.